# Finding a pattern in matrix and based on that dividing by the value in column name

Tags: r

This time it might sound complicated but I believe for some experienced Rusers it will be easy to do. I have a matrix like that:

```
> dput(head(yoe))
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24.5, 
24.5, 32.6, 32.6, 32.6, 32.6), .Dim = c(6L, 21L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("AT1G01050_0", "AT1G01050_1", "AT1G01080_0", "AT1G01080_1", 
    "AT1G01080_2", "AT1G01080_3"), c("10", "33.95", "58.66", 
    "84.42", "110.21", "134.16", "164.69", "199.1", "234.35", 
    "257.19", "361.84", "432.74", "506.34", "581.46", "651.71", 
    "732.59", "817.56", "896.24", "971.77", "1038.91", "MW")))
```

I will use the table to explain better what I want to achieve:

```
            10 33.95 58.66 84.42 110.21 134.16 164.69 199.1 234.35 257.19 361.84 432.74 506.34 581.46 651.71 732.59 817.56 896.24
AT1G01050_0  0     0     0     0      0      0      0     0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
AT1G01050_1  0     0     0     0      0      0      0     0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0
AT1G01080_0  0     0     0     1      0      0      0     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
AT1G01080_1  0     0     0     0      0      0      1     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
AT1G01080_2  0     0     0     0      0      0      0     0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
AT1G01080_3  0     0     0     0      0      0      0     0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0
            971.77 1038.91   MW
AT1G01050_0      0       0 24.5
AT1G01050_1      0       0 24.5
AT1G01080_0      0       0 32.6
AT1G01080_1      0       0 32.6
AT1G01080_2      0       0 32.6
AT1G01080_3      0       0 32.6
```

So first of all. In first row we have a number `1` in column named `234.35`. We take this number from the `colnames` and divide it by the number in the last column in the same row. According to the first row:

`234.35 / 24.5 = 9.56` and this number goes to the next column same row (has to be created, name can be `"Fold"`).

The code should go through all of the rows but number `1` will be in different columns (positions) in this matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `max.col` on the subset of dataset excluding the last column "MW".  Assuming that there is only a single "1" per each row, it is not necessary to specify the "ties.method".  Here, I gave the option as "first".  The index derived from this can be used to get the column name, convert that to 'numeric', divide it by the last column, and `cbind` it with the original dataset.

```
yoe1 <- cbind(yoe, newcol=as.numeric(colnames(yoe[,1:20])[max.col(yoe[,1:20], 
                     'first')])/yoe[,21])
```

Comment: I was expecting atleast couple lines of code... Thx a lot! For some of you it's too easy..

Comment: @Rechlay It is only because I came across similar problems in the past.